# wordpress header javascript - TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have added this to the header.php:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script>
    console.log('TEST');
    document.getElementById("bestyrelsen").innerHTML = "TEST";
</script>
</head>
```

And in the page this p tag:

```
<p id="bestyrelsen"></p>
```

When the page loads TEST is written to the log, but I get this error:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Why is this not working?

Comment: You're trying to execute JS on an element that doesn't exist in the page yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded, wrap your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) which will ensure that the code will be executed when the DOM is fully loaded (all the elements are available):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {  
  console.log('TEST');
  document.getElementById("bestyrelsen").innerHTML = "TEST";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the javascript BEFORE the page is fully loaded, that object didn't exist yet. And it would not exist if that code is in the header.

Try put it in the footer instead.